# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'bool' and 'str' in Odoov10

Tags: string, python-2.7, function, odoo, odoo-10

I got following error when applying function in Odoov10.

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'bool' and 'str'.

My Python code is here:

```py
@api.multi
def name_get(self):
    result = []
    print "re:", result
    for record in self:
        print "R:", record
        name = '[' + record.pet_name + ']' + ' ' + record.name
        result.append((record.id, name))
    return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we do concatenating of more then two string, then we need to make sure that it has string type of values. Otherwise we get same error that you currently faced.

I predict that we have value in *record.name*

Try with following code:

```py
@api.multi
def name_get(self):
    result = []
    for record in self:
        name = '['
        if record.pet_name:
            name += record.pet_name + ']' + ' ' + record.name
        else:
            name += '] ' + record.name
        result.append((record.id, name))
    return result
```

Comment: using 'else' instead of 'elif'

Comment: Hello Odedra,
I want this condition for only particular field. How could i do this? Now, changes reflected for all form. I want only for machine_weigh class.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Yes. That's correct. It will reflect everywhere that you have put Many2one field. It would be good to open new question. So other will get benefit of that answer.

Comment: Hello Odedra, 
Do you have any solution for this problem?

Comment: Yes. I have. That's why I suggest you to open new question.

Comment: I already added this question. Please check and give me solution for this problem.

Comment: Here is my question link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46650219/how-to-add-condition-for-particular-class-to-show-field-drop-down-except-partne