# How to add condition for particular class to show field drop -down except partner_id from res.partner form

Tags: python-2.7, api, if-statement, conditional-statements, odoo-10

I want to access res.partner form in my module. But i want that instead of customer(partner_id) it 'pet_name' in drop-down for only particular class. I applied a function and it's work. But, it work for complete res.partner. But i don't want this. So, any one can provide solution or condition for this problem?

My Code is Here:

class customer_information(models.Model):

```
_inherit = "res.partner"
```

@api.multi

```
def name_get(self):

    result = []

    for record in self:

        name = '['

        if record.pet_name:

            name += record.pet_name + ']' + ' ' + record.name

        else:

            name += '] ' + record.name

        result.append((record.id, name))

    return result
```

pet_name = fields.Char("Pet Name")

```
dog_cat = fields.Selection([('dog', 'Dog'), ('cat', 'Cat')], string="Dog/Cat")

species = fields.Many2one('species.pet', string="Species")

pet_size = fields.Selection([('large', 'Large'), ('medium', 'Medium'), ('small', 'Small')], string="Size")
```

class machine_weight(models.Model):

```
_name = 'machine.weight'

machine_id = fields.Many2one('sale.pet', string='Machine Weight', ondelete='cascade', index=True,

                             copy=False)

pet = fields.Many2one('res.partner')

weight = fields.Integer()

price = fields.Integer()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to pass context and check that context key in *name_get()* method. If we get that context then fire your logic otherwise core logic execute.

For example:

In XML side update code:

```xml
<field name="pet" context="{'need_pet': True}">
```

Now check context key in method.

```
@api.multi
def name_get(self):
    if self._context and self._context.has_key('need_pet'):
        result = []
        for record in self:
            name = '['
            if record.pet_name:
                name += record.pet_name + ']' + ' ' + record.name
            else:
                name += '] ' + record.name
            result.append((record.id, name))
        return result
    return super(customer_information, self).name_get()
```